# Albums not recognaized in channles that sent by another telethon user-bot

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

i have 2 seperate automation on 2 diffrent telegram account , the first automation work great and recognaized albums and send them back to channel , and from this channel the second automation not recognaized the albums, only when i send it nenually , but not with the bot!

this is the code on the second automation that should handle the albums:

```
@client.on(events.Album(chats=config.SRC_CHANNELS, func=lambda e: e.grouped_id))
async def handler(event):
    caption = None
    print('Album found')
    await asyncio.sleep(10)
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(event.messages)):
        caption = list(map(lambda a: str(a.message), event.messages))[count]
        if caption == '':
            count += 1
        else:
            break
    if caption == None or '':
        return
    clean_text = text_clean(caption)
    if clean_text is False:
        return
    for enti in config.DEST_CHANNELS:
        chat = await client.get_entity(enti)
        await client.send_file(entity=chat, file=event.messages, caption=clean_text)
        await asyncio.sleep(6)
    #sending for filtered channels:
    dest_channel = chat_id(clean_text)
    if dest_channel is not False:
        await client.send_file(entity=dest_channel, file=event.messages, caption=clean_text)
        await asyncio.sleep(6)
    else:
        return
```